# Firestore: Filtering nested objects using the PHP SDK

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to filter documents based on the value of an attribute on a nested object.

The user object is structured like this:

```
{
  "username":"Some Dude",
  "messages":{
     "MESSAGE_ID_1":{
         "is_read":true
     },
     "MESSAGE_ID_2":{
         "is_read":false
     }
  }
}
```

I am filtering like this:

```
$db->collection('users')
  ->where('messages.MESSAGE_ID_2.is_read','=',false)
  ->documents()
```

But this is returning no records. Using the console also returns no records.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the "="?

```
$db->collection('users')
  ->where('messages.MESSAGE_ID_2.is_read','=',false)
  ->documents()
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that as the JS library uses that operator. PHP docs use a single `=`. Either way same empty result

Comment: You tried from this guide?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data



```
$citiesRef = $db->collection('cities');
$query = $citiesRef->where('capital', '=', true);
$documents = $query->documents();
foreach ($documents as $document) {
    if ($document->exists()) {
        printf('Document data for document %s:' . PHP_EOL, $document->id());
        print_r($document->fields());
        printf(PHP_EOL);
    } else {
        printf('Document %s does not exist!' . PHP_EOL, $snapshot->id());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup I can get results with a simple where clause that doesn't filter on a deeply nested field